# How to enable FORWARD seek in ffserver?

Tags: ffmpeg, ffserver

I found an ogv file on Internet which when I browse it with FireFox, I can seek to `forward` on it.

I download that file exactly into my server via wget. Then I streamed it via ffserver with following configuration:

```
#ffserver.conf
Port 8080
BindAddress 127.11.170.129
MaxHTTPConnections 2000
MaxClients 1000
MaxBandwidth 1000
CustomLog -
<Stream RadioRobotsThunderRoad.ogv>
File "/var/lib/openshift/52f0d8634382ec1fbb00021a/app-root/data/tmp/RadioRobotsThunderRoad.ogv"
Author "Me"
Copyright "Super MegaCorp"
Title "Test stream from disk"
Comment "Test comment"
</Stream>
```

Now when I browse `http://127.11.170.129:8080/RadioRobotsThunderRoad.ogv` via FireFox, I see that `ffserver` logs it's transfer and also FireFox can play the movie.

The only problem is `I can not seek forward` like the original one?

I searched a lot today with no success, could you experts please help.

Thanks in advance!